# Doubts about queries in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to query names that start with a given name. In MongoBooster I could do that with :

```
find({Name: { $regex:"^FIRST MIDDLE LAST"}})
```

and it took only a second but in C# i have been using LINQ to make my queries.I tried the following LINQ :

```
myCollection.AsQueryable<User>().Where(e => e.Name.StartsWith(_input.name) )
```

But it took so long(more than a minute) that I forcefully killed the operation.

Also, I would like to know which one is better for searhing names in C#, *AsQueryable* or *Find* ?

ANSWER, this is Neil`s answer which worked, I just changed a little bit so that it wouldnt be "var".

```
 FilterDefinition<User> query = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<User>().Regex(x => x.Name , new BsonRegularExpression("^" + _input.name));
 List<User> users = myCollection.Find<User>(query).ToList();
```

Comment: `e.Name.StartsWith(_input.name)` can *probably* only be evaluated in your code, not in Mongo, so you end up pulling every record back so it can check the name.  Hence, it takes a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB `AsQueryable` engine probably can't convert your expression tree into a proper mongodb filter. You should use the raw filter definitions to get better results. These are rather verbose in c# but should still be simple to understand if you are comfortable with the javascript api.

```
var builder = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<BsonDocument>()
            .Regex(x => x["Name"], new BsonRegularExpression("^FIRST MIDDLE LAST"));

var results = myCollection.Find(builder);
```

---

Edit: [Official MongoDB Documentation on C# Linq with `AsQueryable()`](https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver.html)

This actually does say the driver supports `StartsWith()`. If `.Find()` was working significantly faster than `.AsQueryable().Where()` then something is causing causing the linq query to be evaluated in memory rather than translated to a mongo query. Were you possibly using `System.Linq IEnumerable<>.Where()` rather than `MongoDB.Driver.Linq IQueryable<>.Where()`?

Comment: Thanks!It worked! By the way, could you tell me the syntax to limit the query result when using AsQueryable ?

Comment: @kadzu see my edit, it has a link to the documentation for using C# linq with mongodb `AsQueryable()`. To limit the results of your query you can use `myQueryable.Take(100)`

Comment: Thanks, I was in doubt if take would limit the query or just take the the firsts items from the result of the query.